# Configuring Phpschedule it on A WAMP Server

Tags: apache, wamp, chmod, phpscheduleit

I am trying to deploy the Phpscheduleit(http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpscheduleit/) open source software on a WAMP Server version 2.4.

One of the instructions states "The web server must have write access (0755) to /your-booked/tpl_c and /your-booked/tpl" Does anyone have any idea where I could change the write access to 0755?

Thanks.

Comment: You dont need to do that on a windows system. That is an instruction for someone using a Unix/Linus system

Comment: Thanks. That clarified a lot for me.